# flex how to set the tilegroup scroller still keep on the bottom

Tags: apache-flex

My component code is here：

```
<s:BorderContainer id="bcMySeriesParameters" top="100" bottom="45" width="1030"
                   borderVisible="false" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:Scroller id="scrollerForTgpMySeriesParameters" left="5" height="100%" width="1020">
        <s:TileGroup id="tgpMySeriesParameters" left="0" top="0" width="1020"
                     horizontalAlign="center" horizontalGap="5" requestedColumnCount="5"
                     verticalAlign="top" verticalGap="5">
        </s:TileGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

And I have another button which loads more parameters and adds these parameters to the ***tgpMySeriesParameters***. I want to achieve when loading more parameters, the ***scrollerForTgpMySeriesParameters*** still keeps on the bottom, like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the scroller position by using [Scroller.viewport.verticalScrollPosition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html).

In your function that appends more data to your `TileGroup`:

```
scrollerForTgpMySeriesParameters.viewport.verticalScrollPosition = int.MAX_VALUE;
```

For a more advanced scenario (say your scrollbar is halfway down, and you want to keep it at the halfway point out of all the items in the group rather than keep it at the same number of items from the top), you could check the value of `verticalScrollPosition` and then add to it:

```
var numAdded:int = listOfParametersToAddToTheTileGroup.length;
var currentPos:int = scrollerForTgpMySeriesParameters.viewport.verticalScrollPosition;
//add more parameters to your tgpMySeriesParameters
currentPos += numAdded * tileHeight;
scrollerForTgpMySeriesParameters.viewport.verticalScrollPosition = currentPos;
```